# How to import(read) images from excel sheet as per column wise

Tags: c#

using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Spire.Xls;

```
protected void OnReadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile(fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < sheet.Pictures.Count; i++)
    {
        ExcelPicture picture = sheet.Pictures[i];
        picture.Picture.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + picture.Name.Replace(" ", "_") + ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       }
}
```

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: hi, any other way to do capture the images as column wise from excel sheet.any suggestion.?